# Is there any work around to make perl debugger set break points on modules not yet loaded?

Tags: perl, debugging

So that in future the break points take affect as soon as the target file is loaded. Otherwise the debugger hardly helps ...

```
main::(test.pl:7):      Class->new->go;
  DB<1> f Movie.pm
No file matching `Movie.pm' is loaded.
  DB<2> b Movie.pm:10
Subroutine main::Movie not found.
```

I know `Movie.pm` will be loaded and want to set a bp on its 10th line...

Comment: Could you post some more code to give some context to what you're talking about?

Comment: `$a = "A.pm";require $a;`, I want to be able to set bp in `A.pm` regardless whether it's already loaded, at least it should be transparent to a user.

Comment: What does it mean to "set a bp in `A.pm` regardless of whether it's already loaded"?  If you want anyone to help you, you're going to have to provide more explanation.

Comment: What I want is similar to `bu` command of `windbg`,it'll work whether the command is currently loaded or not..

Answer (score 6):

I get round problems like this by manually typing the 'use' line into the debugger.

```
  DB<1> b LWP::Simple::get
Subroutine LWP::Simple::get not found.

  DB<2> use LWP::Simple


  DB<3> b LWP::Simple::get

  DB<4>
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 4):

Workaround: `require` the module when the debugger starts. You can put stuff in your [`.perldb` rc file](http://p3rl.org/debguts) so you don't have to type/paste it every debugger session.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [DOC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebguts.html#Debugger-Internals)

> After each required file is compiled, but before it is executed, DB::postponed(*{"_<\$filename"}) is called if the subroutine DB::postponed exists. Here, the $filename is the expanded name of the required file, as found in the values of %INC.

So you may hook this event and set breakpoints as soon as your module is loaded.

Also you may try the [Devel::DebugHooks](https://metacpan.org/release/Devel-DebugHooks) module. Feel free to ask me on irc.perl.org #debughooks if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

"b postpone" seems to do the trick for me. This works similar to WinDbg's Set Unresolved Breakpoint "bu" command.

I can run this command  when a Perl script breaks into the built-in debugger mode.
Then, Perl honors the breakpoint and automatically stops at the right time.

```
perl -d 
b postpone PackageName::FunctionName
c
```

Reference: https://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug

> #b postpone subname [condition]
>
> Set a breakpoint at first line of subroutine after it is compiled.